# How to get a string description of HKWorkoutActivityType?

Tags: ios, healthkit

I am working on a feature to read HKWorkout samples from the Health app. I'd like to display a description string to the user that tells them what the workout was. The only property I can see that might indicate to the user what type of activity type the sample represents is the `workoutActivityType` property. How am I supposed to convert the HKWorkoutActivityType to a user friendly string? Am I missing something, or is there a better way of getting a description of an HKWorkout sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HealthKit does not have an API for localizing HKWorkoutActivityType values. You need to implement your own mapping.

Comment: Interesting, that’s what I feared. I was hoping there was something I overlooked.

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this? I'm having the same issue and not sure how to implement my own mapping. Any extra insight would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

```
public extension HKWorkoutActivityType {

  /*
   Simple mapping of available workout types to a human readable name.
   */
  var name: String {
    switch self {
    case .americanFootball:             return "American Football"
    case .archery:                      return "Archery"
    case .australianFootball:           return "Australian Football"
    case .badminton:                    return "Badminton"
    case .baseball:                     return "Baseball"
    case .basketball:                   return "Basketball"
    case .bowling:                      return "Bowling"
    case .boxing:                       return "Boxing"
    case .climbing:                     return "Climbing"
    case .crossTraining:                return "Cross Training"
    case .curling:                      return "Curling"
    case .cycling:                      return "Cycling"
    case .dance:                        return "Dance"
    case .danceInspiredTraining:        return "Dance Inspired Training"
    case .elliptical:                   return "Elliptical"
    case .equestrianSports:             return "Equestrian Sports"
    case .fencing:                      return "Fencing"
    case .fishing:                      return "Fishing"
    case .functionalStrengthTraining:   return "Functional Strength Training"
    case .golf:                         return "Golf"
    case .gymnastics:                   return "Gymnastics"
    case .handball:                     return "Handball"
    case .hiking:                       return "Hiking"
    case .hockey:                       return "Hockey"
    case .hunting:                      return "Hunting"
    case .lacrosse:                     return "Lacrosse"
    case .martialArts:                  return "Martial Arts"
    case .mindAndBody:                  return "Mind and Body"
    case .mixedMetabolicCardioTraining: return "Mixed Metabolic Cardio Training"
    case .paddleSports:                 return "Paddle Sports"
    case .play:                         return "Play"
    case .preparationAndRecovery:       return "Preparation and Recovery"
    case .racquetball:                  return "Racquetball"
    case .rowing:                       return "Rowing"
    case .rugby:                        return "Rugby"
    case .running:                      return "Running"
    case .sailing:                      return "Sailing"
    case .skatingSports:                return "Skating Sports"
    case .snowSports:                   return "Snow Sports"
    case .soccer:                       return "Soccer"
    case .softball:                     return "Softball"
    case .squash:                       return "Squash"
    case .stairClimbing:                return "Stair Climbing"
    case .surfingSports:                return "Surfing Sports"
    case .swimming:                     return "Swimming"
    case .tableTennis:                  return "Table Tennis"
    case .tennis:                       return "Tennis"
    case .trackAndField:                return "Track and Field"
    case .traditionalStrengthTraining:  return "Traditional Strength Training"
    case .volleyball:                   return "Volleyball"
    case .walking:                      return "Walking"
    case .waterFitness:                 return "Water Fitness"
    case .waterPolo:                    return "Water Polo"
    case .waterSports:                  return "Water Sports"
    case .wrestling:                    return "Wrestling"
    case .yoga:                         return "Yoga"

    // iOS 10
    case .barre:                        return "Barre"
    case .coreTraining:                 return "Core Training"
    case .crossCountrySkiing:           return "Cross Country Skiing"
    case .downhillSkiing:               return "Downhill Skiing"
    case .flexibility:                  return "Flexibility"
    case .highIntensityIntervalTraining:    return "High Intensity Interval Training"
    case .jumpRope:                     return "Jump Rope"
    case .kickboxing:                   return "Kickboxing"
    case .pilates:                      return "Pilates"
    case .snowboarding:                 return "Snowboarding"
    case .stairs:                       return "Stairs"
    case .stepTraining:                 return "Step Training"
    case .wheelchairWalkPace:           return "Wheelchair Walk Pace"
    case .wheelchairRunPace:            return "Wheelchair Run Pace"

    // iOS 11
    case .taiChi:                       return "Tai Chi"
    case .mixedCardio:                  return "Mixed Cardio"
    case .handCycling:                  return "Hand Cycling"

    // iOS 13
    case .discSports:                   return "Disc Sports"
    case .fitnessGaming:                return "Fitness Gaming"

    // Catch-all
    default:                            return "Other"
    }
  }
}
```

Source : https://github.com/georgegreenoflondon/HKWorkoutActivityType-Descriptions/.

Comment: Thanks, that's actually what I ended up doing