# Retrieve HKWorkoutTypeIdentifier from a HealthKit query

Tags: ios, apple-watch, healthkit

In a HealthKit query, is there a way to retrieve the original HKWorkoutTypeIdentifier used to store the data?

I know you can use HKWorkoutTypeIdentifier to query for specific workout types; but, that's not what I'm trying to do.  The question I want to answer, is "What types of workouts has the user done?"

The Apple Health app has a list, as do some third-party apps.  But I can't figure out how they're doing this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've got the samples returned from the query, you can use `.workoutActivityType` on each workout sample to access the [`HKWorkoutActivityType`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkworkoutactivitytype) that's set for that sample.

Answer (score 0):

Just as Belle said, you can use .workoutActivityType on a sample. However that only returns the HKWorkoutActivityType, which is a Uinit. If you want to display it as a string, for example "running" you need to use the extension mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48600007/how-to-get-a-string-description-of-hkworkoutactivitytype).

Then you can use .name to return a string with the activity type.
So if you have a sample called workout:

`let activityType = workout.workoutActivityType.name`